# Compare the REST response and create new auto generated ID for new record in JET

Tags: javascript, jet, oracle-jet

We have issues with auto generation of ids in oracle JET: it keeps generating duplicates without comparing the REST response records.

We have defined `nextkey=10`, as starting point of my auto number field, and inserted two records, but when I refresh the page, the application starts creating ids from 10

'ID' should auto create after validating the REST response and it should be unique.

```js
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'jquery', 'text!data/endpoints.json', 'ojs/ojarraydataprovider', 'ojs/ojmessages',
'ojs/ojdatagrid', 'ojs/ojcollectiondatagriddatasource', 'my-employee-form/loader'],
    function (oj, ko, $, endpoints, ArrayDataProvider) {
    function DashboardViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        //self.url = 'http://localhost:3000/employees';
        //DSL - DataSourceURL
        self.DSL = JSON.parse(endpoints).employees;

        var data = self.DSL;
        self.collection = new oj.Collection(null, {
            model: new oj.Model.extend({
                idAttribute: 'id',
                urlRoot: self.DSL}),
            url: self.DSL
        });

        self.dataSource = new oj.CollectionDataGridDataSource(
                self.collection, {
                    columns: ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'hire_date', 'salary']
                });

        var nextKey = 10;

        self.inputEmployeeID = ko.observable(nextKey);
        self.inputFirstName = ko.observable();
        self.inputLastName = ko.observable();
        self.inputHireDate = ko.observable();
        self.inputSalary = ko.observable();

        // code goes here
    }
    return new DashboardViewModel();
    }
);
```

Comment: Is it mentioned anywhere in the docs that OJET auto-creates id for you? As far as I know, typing `idAttribute: 'id'` simply tells OJET to use `id` to sort the records. And it will assume `id` is already coming from the REST response.

Comment: thx Ray for response, We have written the function to find the max id from database, and called into Jet code using ajax call and used it in my code.